# pgfplot without borders nor axis doesn't scale up to \textwidth

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{table.dat}
type    v1  v2  v3 v4 v5  v6 v7
t1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6
t2 5 17 4 0 0 0 21 0 133 4 91 0 1 93
t3 18 0 0 0 18 0 15 0 0 111 37 0 0 48
t4 12 0 14 0 0 0 18 0 38 0 38 0 0 30
t5 3 69 4 0 64 0 69 0 80 29 6 0 1 21
t6 28 4 10 0 10 0 33 6 58 0 48 0 21 29
t7 25 144 2 0 0 0 180 0 200 0 193 0 52 370
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      ybar=2pt,
      bar width=3pt,
      width=\textwidth,
      height=3cm,
      axis lines=none,
      ytick=\empty,
      symbolic x coords={ t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7 }
    ]

    \addplot table[x=type, y=v1] {table.dat};
    \addplot table[x=type, y=v2] {table.dat};
    \addplot table[x=type, y=v3] {table.dat};
    \addplot table[x=type, y=v4] {table.dat};
    \addplot table[x=type, y=v5] {table.dat};
    \addplot table[x=type, y=v6] {table.dat};
    \addplot table[x=type, y=v7] {table.dat};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Now, since there are no borders nor ticks nor labels nor anything, I would suppose that `width=\textwidth` would stretch the plot to the margins, but it does not happen.

[image: output]

Can I stretch the plot to the whole `\textwidth`? 
With some adjustable tiny padding, at most.

Please note I don't want to just use `\scalebox` or similar: what I mean is to get the plot have that natural size.

Comment: This won't stretch the plot to `\textwidth`, but if you add `\centering` just after the `\begin{figure}` line, the placement would look nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `scale only axis` key:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{table.dat}
type    v1  v2  v3 v4 v5  v6 v7
t1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6
t2 5 17 4 0 0 0 21 0 133 4 91 0 1 93
t3 18 0 0 0 18 0 15 0 0 111 37 0 0 48
t4 12 0 14 0 0 0 18 0 38 0 38 0 0 30
t5 3 69 4 0 64 0 69 0 80 29 6 0 1 21
t6 28 4 10 0 10 0 33 6 58 0 48 0 21 29
t7 25 144 2 0 0 0 180 0 200 0 193 0 52 370
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      ybar=2pt,
      bar width=3pt,
      width=\textwidth,
      height=3cm,
      scale only axis,
      axis lines=none,
      ytick=\empty,
      symbolic x coords={ t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7 }
    ]

    \addplot table[x=type, y=v1] {table.dat};
    \addplot table[x=type, y=v2] {table.dat};
    \addplot table[x=type, y=v3] {table.dat};
    \addplot table[x=type, y=v4] {table.dat};
    \addplot table[x=type, y=v5] {table.dat};
    \addplot table[x=type, y=v6] {table.dat};
    \addplot table[x=type, y=v7] {table.dat};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]